# How to set GLSL version in shadertoy.com?

Tags: glsl

I just made an account for shadertoy.com today whereas I am new to OpenGL and only know a bit of JavaScript and Processing. I am trying to use a bitwise xor on 2 integers and I get the error as follows:

> '^'  :  bit-wise operator supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only.

I googled and found [this](http://www.shaderific.com/blog/2014/3/13/tutorial-how-to-update-a-shader-for-opengl-es-30). I insert `#version 300 es` at the top of the "Image" tab thingy. I am pleasantly rewarded for my cleverness with the following error:

> 'version'  :  #version directive must occur before anything else, except for comments and white space.

So, my real question is *where should I place the #version directive in Shadertoy?*

Post Scriptum; my experiment is [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsVyRV).

Comment: The page you provided was not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the XOR operator, try opening the same shader in Chrome or some other browser that supports WebGL2. See if your browser supports WebGL2 [here](http://webglreport.com/?v=2).

Answer (score 4):

That's because ShaderToy 'probably' inserts the version for you. And GLSL obliges you to put the version directive at the start of the shader string.You must take into account that the stuff in their GLSL editor is not the whole picture of what is submitted to GLSL compiler. They add more information under the hood which you don't see,and `#version` is one of those hidden things you don't have control of.

Also,it looks like the ShaderToy doesn't support WebGL2, or GLSL 300, which [DOES support](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl20-reference-guide.pdf) XOR operator. So you should contact the owners of the site and ask them when they plan to add the support.

Comment: I figured that it was because the Image tab thingy was not at the top of the text. Maybe there is a different "tab thingy" where it is located. That is what I hope.

Comment: A funny thing is that it seems that it used to support XOR via GLSL 3.00 or webgl2 or something. The google+  post that inspired me to finally try shadertoy shows this screenshot https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-0GiF9IkDdiw/WhSaUsMTJ6I/AAAAAAAApiQ/e7Mo1aPQT30oxy4ej5KDxFAh0cVTmDNzgCJoC/w530-h298-n/ct_ssxr_p0.png but the link leads to this https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4lffzM

Comment: Just realized, you did answer my question sorry for not marking answered thanks